# Calling a function inside forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays

//Array of books

```js
const books = [{
  title: 'The subtle art of not giving a fuck',
  author: 'Mark Manson'
},{
  title: 'Everything is fucked',
  author: 'Mark Manson'
},{
  title: 'Seriousness takes the joyfulness of life',
  author: 'Karan Siddannavar'
}]

const getBooks = book => {
  document.querySelector('.book-list').innerHTML = `<li>${book.title}</li>
<li>${book.author}</li>`
}

books.forEach(book => {
  getBooks(book);
})
```

```html
<div class="book-list"></div>
```

I call the getBooks method every time the book variable is updated with a new object. But, the function gets called only once. In other words, the details of only one book is displayed, even though the function is called every time the forEach loops through the array. Why does this happen?

Comment: It is being called multiple times, you just can't see it because you're overwriting the previous output. Use `+=` instead of `=` to append to `innerHTML`

Comment: better yet, replace `forEach` with `map` and do `innerHTML = books.map(...).join('')`

Answer (score 3):

In each call of the function you are replacing the `innerHTML` (previous content with the current content), you have to use `+=` instead of `=` to retain the previous HTML.

Though, I will suggest you to use [**`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead of `innerHTML`:

```js
const books = [{
  title: 'The subtle art of not giving a fuck',
  author: 'Mark Manson'
},{
  title: 'Everything is fucked',
  author: 'Mark Manson'
},{
  title: 'Seriousness takes the joyfulness of life',
  author: 'Karan Siddannavar'
}]

const getBooks = book => {
  document.querySelector('.book-list').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${book.title}</li>
<li>${book.author}</li>`)
}

books.forEach(book => {
  getBooks(book);
})
```

```html
<div class="book-list"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` method instead of `forEach` and first create content then add it to DOM so you don't have to access DOM in each iteration.

```js
const books = [{
  title: 'The subtle art of not giving a fuck',
  author: 'Mark Manson'
}, {
  title: 'Everything is fucked',
  author: 'Mark Manson'
}, {
  title: 'Seriousness takes the joyfulness of life',
  author: 'Karan Siddannavar'
}]

const getBooks = ({title, author}) => `<li>${title}</li><li>${author}</li>`
const content = books.map(getBooks).join('');
document.querySelector('.book-list').innerHTML = content;
```

```html
<div class="book-list"></div>
```